# Does terraform support adding WCF Relays into Relay Namespace?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm not able to add Shared Access Policy\Auth. rule and WCF Relay into Azure Relay Namespace via Terraform

Plugin : provider.azurerm v2.27.0

There are only 2 resources for Relays
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/relay_namespace.html

Does terraform support this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If is not on the provider documentation: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm then it is not supported ... check the issues see if someone has reported it: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues  if not create a new issue